# I wonder if this ":" is neccessary and what this ":" stands for

Tags: ruby

I'm learning Ruby. You can undef a method from a class:

```
class Person
  undef :talk
end
```

But when I tried this code, I found that if I didn't use ":" sign, it also worked:

```
class Person
   undef talk
end
```

So I wonder if this ":" is neccessary and what this ":" stands for.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`:foo` is a [symbol](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.0/Symbol.html) in Ruby; roughly speaking, it's an interned string whose name is its value.

`Object#undef` [expects the method](http://ruby-doc.org/docs/keywords/1.9/Object.html#method-i-undef) as an argument, per the docs, not a string or symbol. In this particular case, per the documentation, the symbol syntax is incorrect.

Answer (score 2):

`:talk` is a symbol, you should use without `:`

```
undef talk
```

See [Object#undef](http://ruby-doc.org/docs/keywords/1.9/Object.html#method-i-undef)

> Note that the argument to undef is a method name, not a symbol or string.